# ,angularjs modify duplicate property in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, duplicates

I have a json array from database, called donations.

I can't change donations structure because basic_amount from one table and purposes from another,selected with groupby.

```
"donation": [
{"basic_amount": 100, "purposes":[{"name": "pencils"}]},
{"basic_amount": 50, "purposes":[{"name": "books"}]},
{"basic_amount": 100, "purposes":[{"name": "pencils"}]},
]
```

And I put it to templist array as belowed. tempslist array is formatted to the same as database database table. Each row will be save as records.

```
templist =[{"name":"pencils","donate_amount":100},
{"name":"books","donate_amount":50},
{"name":"pencils","donate_amount":100}]
```

I wish to modify donate amount of templist, which is duplicated. So
how can I modify duplicate property in array? 
Should I index in templist and how to index it?

Please check in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MZWlFVP6wLQ11xFzxxzE?p=preview)

Comment: When you say you want to modify the properties in the temp list, are the values in the donations array being changed as well?  And you want to make changes only to the templist and not the donations array?

Comment: Hi user1518802, yes I want to change only templist and not donation array. tempslist array will be saved to database as records. It is out of current issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are creating a duplicate of the model and storing that in the temp array. Do not do this, this kind of pattern will cause you more pain in the future. Store the model that is selected as is any everything becomes so much easier.

Change your sync function to something like the following:

```
$scope.sync = function(bool, donation) {
    //preserve item
    if(bool){
        // add item
        $scope.tempslist.push(donation);
    } else {
        var index = $scope.tempslist.indexOf(donation);
        if (index >= 0) {
            $scope.tempslist.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Enzey, I created templist array because It is the table structure of backend database. So it is different from donation. So I can't put donation as parameter to save. There are some more data in array but these are out of issue. That's why I didn't added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your sync function is pushing the same items into a new array.  Therefore, they have the same reference in memory.  When you change one, the other is changed because the reference is the same.

Angular created the [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) method to create a new array, as well as create new references to all the items in that array allowing you to change anything in the templist without effecting anything in the donations array.

In your sync function, build up new object.

```
var donatedName = {};
var donatedDonation = {};

angular.copy(name, donatedName);
angular.copy(donation, donatedDonation);

donated = {'name': donatedName, 'donate_amount':donatedDonation};
```

Comment: Hi user1518802, I created templist array because It is the table structure of backend database. So there will be donor name, donation date in array to save but it is out of issue. So I can't copy whole list of donations. donations variable is just to extract from database.

Comment: Sure, so keeping you sync function and where you build up the donated object, instead of passing them straight to the object, use angular.copy() to pass in new objects. See updated answer.